# Ruby/Rails - Cannot get size of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, screen-scraping

I'm using the following code to scrape an eBay listing using the scrAPI gem:

I installed this by executing:

```
gem install scrapi
```

I'm also overriding its default text parser by declaring:

```
Scraper::Base.parser :html_parser
```

The problem is that I keep receiving the following error on the `auctions` array size. Not sure what I'm doing wrong? Both `size` and `length` don't work.

```
Scraper.rb:31:in `<class:ScraperDemo>': undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (No
MethodError)Scraper.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

I just run via the commandline:

```
ruby Scraper.rb
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'open-uri'
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
require 'scrapi'

Scraper::Base.parser :html_parser

class ScraperDemo

    ebay_auction = Scraper.define do
        process "h3.ens>a", :description=>:text, :url=>"@href"
        process "td.ebcPr>span", :price=>:text
        process "div.ebPicture >a>img", :image=>"@src"

        result :description, :url, :price, :image
    end

    ebay = Scraper.define do
        array :auctions

        process "table.ebItemlist tr.single", :auctions=>ebay_auction

        result :auctions
    end

    auctions = ebay.scrape(URI.parse('http://search.ebay.com/ipod-nano_W0QQcatrefZC6QQfromZR3QQfsooZ1QQfsopZ1QQkeywordZonQQsacatZQ2d1QQstrkwZipod'))

    # No. of channels found
    puts auctions.size # error occurs on this line number

    # First auction:
    auction = auctions[0]
    puts auction.description
    puts auction.url

end
```

Comment: The error message tells you that `auctions` is `nil`, and is not an array. The problem is not with `size`. You have some problem with line 28. By the way, since your error message gives the line number, it is more reader friendly and polite to give the code with the lines, or at least tell which line the error message is reffering to. Are you asking the people here to count the lines in your code?

Comment: Does auctions.count return anything? What does auctions.type or auctions.class return?

Comment: @ScottJShea Undefined method 'count', Undefined method 'type', auctions.class = NilClass

Comment: Fulvio, as noted that means those method are undefined when used ON NIL  You have nil and nil is not an instance of the auctions class.  This is the #1 error for newbies with rails and ruby, you'll just need to reasd up more and get experience (worked for me).

Comment: Scrapi isn't a popular choice for scraping anymore. You should consider using nokogiri instead.

Comment: @pguardiario ...or Mechanize, which gives you browser-like navigation and also seamlessly exposes Nokogiri for the scraping.

Comment: @Mark I agree mechanize is a great tool when you need to deal with forms or cookies, but overkill in this case.

Comment: @pguardiario I find that Mechanize has a nice enough API that it tends to be easier than Net::HTTP + Nokogiri, even when you don't have links to click, boxes to check, etc. But the extra power is there should you need it.

Comment: @Mark - Yes but consider open-uri (which he already mentions) + nokogiri and whether it's wise to recommend 2 unfamiliar libraries when 1 will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Nokogiri as my scraper of choice.